# How to increment/decrement tkinter spinbox value via keyboard press?

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is my code -

```
import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
from threading import Thread


list1 = np.arange(-30.8, 104.2, 5.0)
list2 = np.arange(-10.8, 104.2, 5.0)
print(list)
# window = tk()
root = tk.Tk()


def on_key_R_press(event):
    """
    Code logic here
    """


root.bind("<r >", on_key_R_press)


def c2c_sl():
    spinbox.config(values=list2)


c2c_button = tk.Button(
    root, text="C2C SL", command=lambda: Thread(target=c2c_sl).start()
).place(x=50, y=32)


spinbox = tk.Spinbox(root, values=list1)
spinbox.place(x=50, y=50)
root.mainloop()
```

I want to automatically update (next value in numpy array) value of the spinbox by pressing r key via function on_key_R_press, how can I do that ?

Comment: You just need to write a function.

Comment: Do you mean that pressing the `r` key does the same as clicking the up button of the spinbox?